# Adding Type A to Type B (ObservableCollection Items)

Tags: c#, wpf, listbox, observablecollection, updating

I've got Two ObservableCollections:

- WorkingFileList
- ProjectFileList

To fill both those collections I have two classes which inherit INotifyPropertyChanged:

- WorkingFileItem (adds to the WorkingFileList collection)
- ProjectFileItem (adds to the ProjectFileList collection)

In terms of properties, they both have the exact same strings and names:

```
public class WorkingFileItem : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        string name;
        public string Name
        {
            get { return name; }
            set
            {
                if (name != value)
                    name = value; OnPropertyChanged("Name");
            }
        }

        string filepath;
        public string FilePath
        {
            get { return filepath; }
            set
            {
                if (filepath != value)
                    filepath = value; OnPropertyChanged("FilePath");
            }
        }


        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
        {
            if (PropertyChanged != null)
                PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }

    public class ProjectFileItem : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        string name;
        public string Name
        {
            get { return name; }
            set
            {
                if (name != value)
                    name = value; OnPropertyChanged("Name");
            }
        }

        string filepath;
        public string FilePath
        {
            get { return filepath; }
            set
            {
                if (filepath != value)
                    filepath = value; OnPropertyChanged("FilePath");
            }
        }

        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
        {
            if (PropertyChanged != null)
                PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }
```

I've binded two listboxes using:

```
ObservableCollection<WorkingFileItem> WorkingFileList = new ObservableCollection<WorkingFileItem>();
LB1.ItemsSource = WorkingFileList 
ObservableCollection<ProjectFileItem> ProjectFileList = new ObservableCollection<ProjectFileItem>();
LB2.ItemsSource = ProjectFileList
```

**Problem:**

I might want to update an Item in ProjectFileList(e.g. updating index positions of items in the listbox) and then add that updated Item to the other collection.

E.g. If I changed ItemXYZ's Index in ProjectFileList to go to the top of the list, I would want to add that ItemXYZ into WorkingFileList but I don't think I can because they are both two different objects. I will need to check if some items are already in one list and if they are not then do whatever etc. but I can't because they are both different objects. What would I have to do to add the items to other ObservableCollection?

**Edit**

I've tried using the same class (WorkingFileItem) for both collections. Then proceeded to check the index of a specific item in the WorkingFileList but no luck. Code was:

```
WorkingFileItem item = (WorkingFileItem)lbProjectsFiles.SelectedItem;
Int index = WorkingFileList.IndexOf (item);
```

The code above returns -1 even though the item exists in the WorkingFileList

Comment: Why do you have two classes (models) with the same properties but different names? Just use one class to represent objects in two collections. You will avoid a problem with different objects when you want to add item of one type to collection of another types.

Comment: @marcinax I'm using two different ListboxItem Templates, one with same textblocks and Image, other with No Image.

Comment: @F4z still - where's a problem with having one class ? makes no sense to create two exactly same classes - code duplication

Comment: @MajkeloDev I'll try the changes and see how it goes.

Comment: So I still don't see a reason of using two different classes with the same properties. Now, use one class but if you want add any properties to one of the models in the future, you can use inheritance.

Comment: @marcinax I'm trying to do  int oldIndex = WorkingFileList.IndexOf((WorkingFileItem)lblProjectFiles.SelectedItem); to get the index of the selected object but returns -1. What could be the cause? I'm using WorkingFileItem for both Collections

Comment: Where are you trying to get SelectedItem? Are you sure it isn't null? Did you subscribed on SelectionChanged event?

Comment: @marcinax It isn't null, No, it's not subscribed on SelectionChanged but on MouseDoubleClick however I get the same result when I change it on SelectionChanged

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me that you have two different sets of similar (but not same) objects, that's why your code 
`WorkingFileItem item = (WorkingFileItem)lbProjectsFiles.SelectedItem;
Int index = WorkingFileList.IndexOf (item);`

is not working. The simplest way to resolve that situation is to override `Equals()` method of WorkingFileItem:

```
public override bool Equals(System.Object obj)
{
    if (obj == null)
    {
        return false;
    }

    WorkingFileItem item = obj as WorkingFileItem;

    return Equals(item);
}

public bool Equals(WorkingFileItem item)
{
    if (item == null)
    {
        return false;
    }

    return (Name == item.Name) && (FilePath == item.FilePath);
}

public override int GetHashCode()
{
    return Name.GetHashCode() ^ FilePath.GetHashCode();
}
```

But you definitely have to review your architecture.